# Using #ifdef with enum in C

Tags: c, enums, conditional-compilation

I want to use `#ifdef` like below. But i'm not sure that it is suitable usage. Because i'm taking error from compiler. It says like `undefined identifier ENUM1` . Have you ever used `#ifdef` like this. ???

```
typedef enum
{

#ifdef DEFINITION1
    ENUM1,  
#endif

#ifdef DEFINITION2
    ENUM2,          
#endif

#ifdef DEFINITION3
    ENUM3           
#endif
}teSomething;
```

Thanks for helping...

Comment: Please post a proper [mcve]. If you're not defining `ENUM1`, you mustn't use it either!

Comment: Pretty much certain this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles just fine: https://godbolt.org/g/dRaR85

if you want to use `ENUM2` for example you of course need to define `DEFINITION2`and if you want to use `ENUM3` you have to define `DEFINITION3`. Because otherwise the `#ifdef` will always be false and never define the ENUM.

I've never used `#ifdef` like this but I have done this:

```
#ifdef VULKAN
enum Format{
    RGB = VK_RGB
};  
#elif DIRECTX
enum Format{
    RGB = DX12_RGB
};
#else
enum Format { // Empty enum for safety reasons.
};
#endif
```